# How can I send List< string[] > using NetworkComms.Net

Tags: c#, sockets, system.net.sockets

There is a server and a client. I am trying to send a list of string arrays (List< string[] >) from the server to the client. I want to learn how to correctly serialise such an object. So far I have the following:

Server side:

```
 NetworkComms.SendObject("test", clientIP, clientPort, testData.AsParallel().ToList());
```

Client Side:

```
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<List<string[]>>("test", DoSomething);
```

DoSomething function:

```
private static void DoSomething (PacketHeader header, Connection connection, List<string[]> testData)
    //do stuff
}
```

I get the following error when I do this:

> objectToSerialize must implement IExplicitlySerialize
>
> Parameter name: objectToSerialize